# Update fields with geometry properties (X-coordinate and Y-coordinate of "true" centroid)

Tags: arcpy, geometry, cursor

I've been trying to take the X and Y coordinates of the true centroid from a polygon shapefile I have called HamDA.shp and add such coordinates to two float fields called X and Y (with 12 precision and 2 scale) that exist within HamDA.shp.

I know I need to use an Update Cursor to accomplish this task, but i'm not entirely sure how to set it up properly.

Here's what I have so far:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Users/Alex/SampleData"
fc = "HamDA.shp" 

vertexarray = arcpy.Array()
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,["SHAPE@"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        for vertex in row[0]:
            vertexarray.add(vertex.X,vertex.Y)
            cursor.updateRow(vertexarray)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also just use the [Add Geometry Attributes](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-geometry-attributes.htm) tool.

You have the choice to add `CENTROID` or `CENTROID_INSIDE` coordinates.

If you really want to use a cursor, you need to use the `SHAPE@TRUECENTROID` token, it returns a tuple with X, Y coordinates. Then call the X and Y by their index:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, "SHAPE@TRUECENTROID") as cur:
    for row in cur:
        print """X = {}, Y = {}""".format(row[0][0], row[0][1])
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by true centroid but this will work on "normal" centroids. I use the SHAPE@X and SHAPE@Y tokens to get the centroid coordinates of each feature and then add these in two columns:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Users/Alex/SampleData"
fc = "HamDA.shp"

arcpy.AddField_management(in_table='fc', field_name='CentroidX', field_type='DOUBLE')
arcpy.AddField_management(in_table='fc', field_name='CentroidY', field_type='DOUBLE')

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,['SHAPE@X','SHAPE@Y','CentroidX','CentroidY']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[2]=row[0]
        row[3]=row[1]
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: how do return centroids coordinates in decimal degrees?

Comment: @Geo.Dude you should be able to use projectas method of point geometry (http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/pointgeometry.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to delete row and cursor.
Use Shape@XY and call x and y using their indexes. You can use x and y separately.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Users/Alex/SampleData"
fc = "HamDA.shp" 

vertexarray = arcpy.Array()
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,["SHAPE@XY","X","Y"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[1] = row[0][0]
        row[2]= row[0][1]
        cursor.updateRow(row)
del row
del cursor
```